# A characteristic-free proof that the action of a connected algebraic group $G$ on the fundamental group of a $G$-variety is trivial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $G$ be an algebraic group (not necessarily linear) defined over an
algebraically closed field $k$,
acting on a smooth integral $k$-variety $X$.
Let $x_0\in X(k)$ and let $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ denote the étale
(Grothendieck's) fundamental group of $X$.
Assume that either $G$ fixes $x_0$ or the group $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is abelian.
In both cases $G(k)$ acts on $\pi_1(X,x_0)$.
I need a proof that if $G$ is *connected*, then this action is trivial.

I know a proof in characteristic 0.
In this case by the Lefschetz principle we may assume that
$k=\mathbf{C}$, and we can consider
the action of $G(\mathbf{C})$ on the topological fundamental group
$\pi_1^{\mathrm{top}}(X(\mathbf{C}),x_0)$.
Let $g\in G(\mathbf{C})$.
Since $G$ is connected, we can connect $g$ with the unit element $e\in
G(\mathbf{C})$ by a continuous path.
We see that the automorphism $g_*\colon X(\mathbf{C})\to
X(\mathbf{C})$ is homotopic to the identity automorphism.
It follows that the induced automorphism of
$\pi_1^{\mathrm{top}}(X(\mathbf{C}),x_0)$ is the identity.

I would like to see a proof that the action is trivial in *arbitrary*
characteristic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is false as stated in positive characteristic. For example, suppose that the characteristic of $k$ is $p$; take $X = \mathbb A^1_k = \mathop{\rm Spec} k[t]$ and $G = \mathbb G_{\rm m}$. If $a \in k^*$ and $E$ is the standard étale cover $E = \mathop{\rm Spec} k[x,t]/(x^p - x - t) \to \mathop{\rm Spec} k[t]$ of $X$, its pullback through multiplication by $a$ is $ \mathop{\rm Spec} k[x,t]/(x^p - x - at) \to \mathop{\rm Spec} k[t]$, which will not be isomorphic to $E$ in general.

However, it is true when $X$ is proper over $ \mathop{\rm Spec} k$. The point is that in this case we have $\pi_1(X \times G, (x_0, 1)) = \pi_1(X, x_0) \times \pi_1(G, 1)$ (see, for example, Corollary 5.6.6 in Szamuely's wonderful book on the fundamental group); this uses the hypothesis that $G$ is connected. The embedding of $\pi_1(G, 1)$ corresponding in the decomposition above is induces by the embedding $G \subseteq X \times G$ defined by $g \mapsto (x_0, g)$. If $\alpha \colon X \times G \to X$ is the action, let us show that $\alpha_*\colon \pi_1(X \times G, (x_0, 1)) \to \pi_1(X, x_0)$ coincides with the homomorphism $\pi_1(X \times G, (x_0, 1)) \to \pi_1(X, x_0)$ induced by the first projection. From the formula above we see that it is sufficient to show that the composite $G \to X \times G \to X$, where the first map is $g \mapsto (x_0, g)$ and the second is the action, induces a trivial map on fundamental groups. But the map is in fact constant, because $G$ fixes $x_0$, so this is clear.

Now fix $g \in G(k)$. The composite $X \to X \times G \to X$, where the first map is $x \mapsto (x,g)$, and the second is the action, induces the action of $g$ on $X$. On the other hand, the composite $X \to X \times G \to X$, where the first map is $x \mapsto (x,g)$, and the second is the projection, induces the identity. From the previous fact, we have that these two maps induce the same homorphism on fundamental groups, and we are done.

Comment: A related question: What is the fundamental group of $\mathbb A^1_k$ as a scheme (or, if it's not representable, as a functor)?

Comment: @Angelo: Could you please add details? Why "if $\alpha \colon X \times G \to X$ is the action, we need to show that $\alpha_*\colon \pi_1(X \times G, (x_0, 1)) \to \pi_1(X, x_0)$ coincides with the homomorphism $\pi_1(X \times G, (x_0, 1)) \to \pi_1(X, x_0)$ induced by the first projection"? How is this related to the assertion that any element $g\in G(k)$ acts trivially on $\pi_1(X, x_0)$? Also, why
"this is clear from the formula above, since the elements of $\pi_1(G, 1)$ go to the identity, because $G$ fixes $x_0$"? And where do you use the assumption that $G$ is connected?

Comment: To André: I am not sure what you are asking. What's "the fundamental group as a functor"?

To Mikhail: I will add more details.

Comment: to  André: if $char(k)=0$ then $\pi_{1}(\mathbb{A}_{k}^{1}=\pi_{1}(Spec(k))$. If $char(k)=p>0$ then the question is more delicate. Anyway it still exists a map $\pi_{1}(\mathbb{A}_{k}^{1} \rightarrow \pi_{1}(Spec(k))$ which is surjective, but not injective. So for example if the field k is of non-zero characteristic and separably closed, then $\pi_{1}(\mathbb{A}_{k}^{1}$ is non-trivial.  

Comment: @André: The precise structure of the fundamental group of an affine curve $X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$ is not known. Assume that $X$ is the complement to $r\geq 1$ points in a projective connected smooth curve of genus $g$. Then, Abhyankar's conjecture, proved by Raynaud (for $X=\mathbf A^1_k$) and Harbater, states that a finite group $G$ is a quotient of $\pi_1(X)$ if and only its maximal prime-to-$p$ quotient $G'$ is the fundamental group of the analogous curve in characteristic zero, i.e., is generated by $2g-2+r-1$ elements.

Comment: @ACL: Thank you. This is very informative.